# How to DRY Capistrano recipes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, recipe

I am using Ruby on Rails and the Capistrano gem. I would like to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) a Capistrano recipe.

In the `deploy.rb` file I have:

```
# First task
task :first_task do
  ...

  run "cd #{current_path}; #{try_sudo} chmod -R 666 /log/production.log"
end

# Second task
task :second_task do
  run "..."

  # The following code is equal to that stated in the first task.
  run "cd #{current_path}; #{try_sudo} chmod -R 666 /log/production.log"
end
```

So, **how can I DRY the above code so to have not duplicated tasks?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capistrano code is just ruby code with a Domain Specific Language (DSL), so you should be able to do:

```
def chmod_log
  run "cd #{current_path}; #{try_sudo} chmod -R 666 /log/production.log"
end

# First task
task :first_task do
  ...

  chmod_log
end

# Second task
task :second_task do
  run "..."

  # The following code is equal to that stated in the first task.
  chmod_log
end
```